# $ \|u(x)+u(x)-x +o(\|x\|^p)\|<r $?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, numerical-methods

Set $B_r=\{ x\in \mathbb{R}^n : \|x-0\|< r \}$ for any $r>0$. Let $C^p_0(B_r,B_r)$ the set of all  smooth functions  $u:B_r \to B_r$ of class $C^p$ such that $u(0)=0$. I would like to prove the following inequality for $r> 0$ small enough. I do not know if it's necessarily true.
$$
\|u(x)+u(x)-x +o(\|x\|^p)\|<r
$$
here $o(\|x\|^p)$ is the [little o notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) or [Landau Symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LandauSymbols.html). 
One of my attempts were. 
\begin{align*}
\|u(x)+u(x)-x +o(\|x\|^p)\| \leq
&
\|2Du(0)\cdot x-x +o(\|x\|)+o(\|x\|^p)\|
\\
\leq
&
\|2\cdot Du(0)-I\|_{\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{\mathbb{R}^n},\mathbb{\mathbb{R}^n})}\|x\| +o(\|x\|)+o(\|x\|^p)\|
\\
\end{align*}
Here $\|\;\cdot \;\|_{\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{\mathbb{R}^n},\mathbb{\mathbb{R}^n})}$ is the usual matrix norm in $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$.

But I have no control over $\|Du(0)\|$ or $o(\|x\|^p)$ to ensure that $\|2Du (0) + I\|+\epsilon r^{p-1}<1$ is one suficentemente small amount.

Comment: You have $u(x)+u(x) -\dots$ in the first display formula.